# Powershell to Event

Tags: powershell, powershell-2.0

I've tried to make a PowerShell script that writes an event when the text files in an folder are older than 15 minutes.

This is the code I'm trying to use:

```
$targetfile=get-childitem C:\Users\user\Desktop\bizin\*.txt

if ($targetfile.AddMinutes -15 ) 

{

write-eventlog -logname Application -source ESENT -eventID 9999 -entrytype Error -message "No new files in 15min gate is down!" -category 3 

'create event log to say bad things have happened'

}
```

I always get the event when I run the script. I would like to only get an event when the file is older than 15 minutes. It's going to be a scheduled task to run every 15 minutes.

Comment: based on [technet](https://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/office/en-US/41bea897-00c1-424f-a23f-c38d67bc0e32/powershell-script-help-get-a-file-created-date-for-multiple-machines?forum=winserverpowershell) you should use     
 $FileDate = (Get-ChildItem \\$computer\c$\temp\logfile.txt).CreationTime
to get the time

Answer (score 3):

You need to access the `LastWriteTime` property of the file and compare it with a `DateTime` object:

```
$targetFiles = Get-ChildItem -Path 'C:\Users\user\Desktop\bizin\' -Filter *.txt
foreach ($targetFile in $targetFiles)
{
    if ($targetFile.LastWriteTime -lt [DateTime]::Now.AddMinutes(-15))
    {
        # Write the eventlog....
    }
}
```

**Note:** You can use the `-Filter` parameter for the [Get-ChildItem cmdlet](http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkID=113308) to retrieve only `txt`files. 
Here is the same example with use of aliases and the pipeline in just one line:

```
gci -Path 'C:\Users\user\Desktop\bizin\' -Filter *.txt | ? { $_.LastWriteTime -lt [DateTime]::Now.AddMinutes(-15) } | % { <# Write the eventlog... #> }
```